# Configure Eclipse IDE to move cache data out of eclipse installation direction

Tags: eclipse

I believe this is normal user's behavior:
After downloading the eclipse IDE distribution, such as eclipse-jee-mars-2-win32-x86_64.zip file, you unzip it to a folder, e.g. C:. The eclipse executable is at C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe. (Here I'll refer C:\eclipse directory as eclipse home directory.)

When running, eclipse will write some temp or customization file under eclipse home directory, so the eclipse home directory became dirty. I wonder if there is any parameter or configuration file setting so eclipse will write those cache/temp/customized data to somewhere else.

I'm not talking about '-clean' parameter. From the help file, I think I should try **-configuration configURL**. However I don't know the format of the configuration file.

Comment: The configuration area is a directory containing all sorts of things. Look at the `.configuration` directory in your install.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best I've got so far after some trial and errors:

Take **C:\eclipse** as my eclipse home directory, which is extracted from eclipse distribution zip file. My goal is to keep this home directory clean.

I created the following directories:

```
C:\eclipse-work.ws
C:\eclipse-work.home\user  
C:\eclipse-work.home\configuration
```

Here is the command line I used to start eclipse, of course it's part of a script:
**C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe -data C:\eclipse-work.ws -user C:\eclipse-work.home\user -configuration C:\eclipse-work.home\configuration**
The trick is I need to make configuration directory to be a two level directory as eclipse will generate other cache or data under **C:\eclipse-work.home** dir.

This is the best I can get so far. All cache data, as well as plug-ins I installed, will be in the **C:\eclipse-work.home** directory. There is only one file generated under original eclipse home directory, that is a profile gz file under

```
p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\profileRegistry\epp.package.jee.profile
```

directory. And this file won't be changed once it's created.

I'm using a ram disk. Using above approach I can setup the eclipse IDE in the ram disk image file. Now eclipse starts much faster.

For that **-user** directory, so far I didn't observe any file generated under it. Not sure if it can be omitted.